# random walk on $Z$ by step $X_1$

Tags: probability, random-walk

Let $S_n$ be a random walk on $Z$ by step $X_1$. Let's suppose
$P (X_1 =   -1) = P (X_1 = 1) = P (X_1 = 2) = 1/3$
Check what kind of walk is $S_n$: recursive or transitive.

I tried to proceed with this well known result that random walk is transient iff:

$\mathbb{E}N = \lim_{t \to 1^-} \int_{[-\pi , \pi]^d}\frac{ds}{(2 \pi)^d(1-t\varphi(s))} < \infty$, where $N = \sum_{n \geq 0}\mathbb{1}_{\{S_n = S_0\}}$.

I was stuck on figuring out the $\varphi(t)$, any help there and in the next steps will be appreciated.

I got to the moment of
$$
\varphi(t) = \frac{2}{3}\cos(t) + \frac{1}{3}e^{2it}
$$
and I got lost with the imaginary part of it ($\frac{1}{3}e^{2it}$) in the limitation of $1-\varphi(s)$ the integral.

Answer (score 0):

No such complicated criterion is needed. The answer is immediate from SLLN.

$\frac {S_n} n \to EX_1=\frac 2 3 $ a.s. by SLLN's. Hence $S_n \to \infty$ a.s., which shows that  $(S_n)$ is transient. [$P(S_n=0 \, i.o.]=0$].

Comment: Can someone explain the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but this more complicated criteria told me that $S_n$ is [recurrent...](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral_-pi+to+pi+1%2F%281+-+2%2F3*cos%28t%29+-+1%2F3*exp%282*i*t%29%29)

Comment: @ljaniec It is not recurrent. Even intuition suggests that the random walk is moving off to $+\infty$.

Comment: I understand your intuition, but there is a need for a more strict approach to conducting that $S_n$ is transient... I tried suggested result and got a contradiction - if you could find any mistake in use of it there, I would happy stay corrected.

Comment: @ljaniec My argument is 100% rigorous. If $S_n \to \infty$ with probability $1$ then $(S_n)$ cannot be recurrent and this follows from **definition** of recurrence.

Comment: I didn't want to discredit your solution, I just wanted to find out why this result I got above was different :)